# Automated UI testing a large c# forms app

Tags: c#, forms, acceptance-testing, gui-testing

I am working on a fairly complicated project.  We have a c# forms app that has several layers of business logic, communicating with a c++ hardware management layer via a socket interface.

We have unit test coverage of the c++ side, and the business logic, but acceptance testing of the forms app is a whole new world for me, as we have done exclusively web apps heretofore.

Any suggestions on where to start?  I looked at NUnitUI, but I'm not sure that it has enough depth to do what we need.  I am looking for a suite to do automated UI testing.

Also, I am okay with paying for the right solution if that is what I need to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify...are you looking for a product to manage the results of User Acceptance testing or are you looking to automate UI testing?

Comment: Hah, good point, automated UI testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [TestComplete](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/?bb=tc7), it is a pretty flexible testing framework for WinForms.

Answer (score 3):

[White](http://www.codeplex.com/white) is an interesting free alternative.